# Checking the neighbour values of arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array of numbers with length `L`, and I have to make the program check the sums of every array element with its preceding and following neighbors.

So, for example, if I have the array being `{1, 2, 3}`, the output for the 2nd element should be `6` because `1 + 2 + 3 = 6` and they are all neighbors.

If the chosen element is the first element in the array, its preceding neighbor is the last element of the array, and if the element is the last element in the array, the following neighbor is the first element of the array.  So, in the `{1, 2, 3}` example, no matter what number you check, you always get `6`, but if it were `{1, 2, 3, 4}` instead, the answer for the 3rd element would be `9` because `3 + 2 + 4 = 9`.

I hope you understood how it should work.

The problem I am getting is that the output is out of control. I tried to check the array itself and it is completely normal. In the `{1, 2, 3}` example, I get an output of `7208681` and I don't know why.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int total;
    cin >> total;
    int Bush[total]; //array of numbers

    int temp, output = 0; //output variable and a container for the last resurt a.k.a temp

    for (int i = 0; i <= total - 1; i++)
    {
        cin >> Bush[i]; //inputting the array elements
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
            output = Bush[i] + Bush[i + 1] + Bush[total]; //checking if the loop checks the first number
        if (i == total - 1)
            output = Bush[i] + Bush[0] + Bush[i - 1]; //checking if the loop checks the first number

        temp = output;                                //assigning the temp value to the current output value
        output = Bush[i] + Bush[i + 1] + Bush[i - 1]; //assigning a new output value

        if (temp > output)
            output = temp; //checking values
    }

    cout << output << endl; //outputting
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, `int Bush[total];` - don't do that. VLAs are not standard compliant. use a `std::vector<int> Bush(total);`. And fyi, this whole thing falls apart when `total` isn't successfully read, so you may as well fix that while you're at it. Finally, something tells me the *modulo* operator would make most of the conditionals in this code disappear. Look in to that too.

Comment: the last element is total-1, not total, the if (i==0) line is accessing garbage past the end of the array.

Comment: off-topic, but comments like "assigning the temp value to the current output value" are completely unnecessary. Everyone knows what `temp = output` does. If you're going to comment, you should comment on things that aren't immediately apparent.

Answer (score 1):

When `i = 0`, the expression `Bush[i-1]` results in accessing an invalid location of the array `(- 1)`.

Similarly, when `i = total - 1` (last index of iteration), the expression  `Bush[i+1]` gives you an index of `total` which is out of bounds of the array.

Answer (score 0):

The last element of `Bush` is at index `total -1`, but you are accessing `Bush[total]` when `i==0`

Comment: if(i == 0)output = Bush[i] + Bush[i+1] + Bush[total]; //Bush[total] is wrong should be Bush[total-1]

Comment: there were some comments now deleted...so I thought that an edit was a kind of messing up the thing...

Answer (score 0):

I think the below code would work

```
int main()
{
int total;

cout << "Enter Number of Elements " << endl;
cin>>total;
int Bush[total];//array of numbers
int temp = 0, output = INT_MIN; //output variable and a container for the last resurt a.k.a temp
cout << "Enter the Elements " << endl;

for(int i = 0; i<=total - 1; i++)
{
    cin>>Bush[i];//inputting the array elements
}
for(int i = 0; i<total; i++)
{
    if(i == 0)
        temp = Bush[i] + Bush[i+1] + Bush[total -1];//checking if the loop checks the first number

    else if(i == total - 1)
        temp = Bush[i] + Bush[0] + Bush[i-1];//checking if the loop checks the first number
    else
        temp = Bush[i] + Bush[i+1] + Bush[i-1]; //assigning the temp value to the current output value

    output = (temp > output)?temp:output;

}
cout<<output<<endl;//outputting
return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks for sharing this code, but I have only the question why is temp equal to INT_MIN

Comment: sorry actually output should be INT_MIN, I modified the above code, because for the first time, the temp value can be negative number, but still output should save that value or if your list is (-1,-2,-3) result should be -6 but the program may output 0 if output is initialized to 0 instead of INT_MIN

Answer (score 0):

At the end, there are many mistakes in your code, nonetheless, the problem with the if/else structure.

I would suggest you to use another inner loop, based on module operator that simplify the code a lot:

```
int max = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<total; i++)
{
  output = Bush[i] + Bush[(i+1)%total] + Bush[(i-1+total)%total];
  if(max < output) max = output;//checking the max
}
cout<<max<<endl;//outputting
```

that does the operation you required.

Hope this may help.